# How to do drag and drop functionality in canvas using fabric js?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, canvas, html5-canvas, magento-1.7, fabricjs

I am working on magento 1.7 version and using fabric js for drag and drop functionality.
Actually, I have some images from facebook using facebook api now when I drag them on canvas they successfully placed on canvas but an error show on console like below:-

**HTML to canvas SecurityError: The operation is insecure in following function**

```
function loadTexture(canvas) {
activeTexture = null;
activeTexture = new gx.Texture(canvas.getContext("2d").getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height));
forceRedraw = true;
```

}

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you should post the entire code.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting that error because you're drawing an image or font to the canvas that has a different origin from the page that holds the canvas, which disallows `getImageData` from working, for security reasons. (See [Understanding the HTML5 Canvas image security rules](http://simonsarris.com/blog/480-understanding-the-html5-canvas-image-security-rules))